# String parameters are not passing in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, petapoco

i want to pass parameters for details page. but my parameters are not passing. In my table primary key is ExpRef. How i can pass this string parameter in details page...

```
public ActionResult Details(string id)
        {
            var db = new PetaPoco.Database("Cboofinal");
            var d = db.Query<OdeExport>("select * from OdeExport where ExpRef=@0",id);
            return View(d);
        }
```

Comment: How are you calling the action?

Comment: @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ExpRef })

Comment: and are you sure the ExpRef property is being populated? What url is rendered by asp.net for that ActionLink?